# What is the correct setup for Brew + Zsh + Oh My Zsh on multiple admin users on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

My question is what would be a good way to run two admin accounts for developing in regards to running `Homebrew`, `Zsh` and `Oh My Zsh` and configuring the `.zshrc` file?

My reasoning for this is that I recently started a new job and would like to use my Mac with two accounts, both of which will be admins and both of which I will require devtools so as to keep my work life/dev and personal life/dev cleanly separated. I just erased my hard drive and cleanly installed OS X 10.12.3 and created two Admin accounts.

I've had a shot at setting it up however keep getting permission errors whenever I switch accounts and run terminal, usually specific to zsh completions.

My steps:

1. Install Homebrew on both users `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`.
2. Install zsh with brew `brew install zsh` and change to it `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
3. Install oh my zsh with curl via `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`.
4. run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`.

Then I've tried a whole mess of things which I'll refrain from adding as I believe they may only lead others down a dark path.

Comment: 1. You do not need to install `ruby`. Sierra comes with it. 2. You don't need to install `zsh`. Again, Sierra comes with it. 3. `export ZSH=<destinationpath>` before running the installation script. 4. Allow world execute for executables scripts, allow world read for readable files and allow read-execute for directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this step is safe to run as root, I still recommend running the installation as non-root user to prevent catastrophic problems with root switching shell while the shell isn't working. superuser shell should never be changed.

Here's the proper way to install `oh-my-zsh` for multiple users.

Step 1: Ensure umask is not stricter than 022. If not set it to 022.

```
$ umask 022
```

Step 2: set and export ZSH with the destination path where the shared oh-my-zsh will be installed.

```
export ZSH=/usr/local/.zsh/oh-my-zsh
```

Step 3: Create the parent directory and make it owned by the user installing the scripts.

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/.zsh
$ sudo chown ${USER} /usr/local/.zsh
```

Step 4: Run the installer.

```
$ bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Step 5: Change ownership of the installation path back to root.

```
$ sudo chown -R root /usr/local/.zsh
```

Step 6: Update location of ZSH in `${ZSH}/templates/zshrc.zsh-template`

```
$ sudo sed -i 's|export ZSH=.*|export ZSH='${ZSH}'|' ${ZSH}/templates/zshrc.zsh-template
```

(Optional)
Step 7: Disable auto update. This is recommended as the installation is now owned by root.

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"/DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"/' ${ZSH}/templates/zshrc.zsh-template
```

From here on, each user can copy `${ZSH}/templates/zshrc.zsh-template` as ~/.zshrc

Comment: When running step 6 I get the error "sed: 1: "/usr/local/.zsh/oh-my-z ...": extra characters at the end of l command".

Comment: You can ignore steps 6 and 7. Those are optional

Comment: @joshuatvernon  - just skip step6. And when copying template to a user, just modify the file via `vim`.

Comment: when you say copying template to a user am I meant to have a file named `zshrc.zsh-template` instead of `.zshrc` that I'm used to?

Comment: @joshuatvernon  - No. You will copy it as `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I apolagise, I am still getting the exact same issues. May I ask which steps I have to perform on which users? It sounded like the steps only needed to be performed on one user

Comment: @joshuatvernon - `sudo` is probably overriding the value of `umask`. If this is the case, then step3 would create a very restrictive permission. Check and make sure permission of `/usr/local/.zsh` is `755`. If not `755`, then set it to `755`.

Comment: You only need to perform steps 1 to 5 once. Perform step 7 on all users.

Comment: This procedure worked for me and I am running Macos Sierra. Yours should work using this procedure too.

Comment: Since I've installed zsh via homebrew should I be using the zsh located at `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh` instead?

Comment: @joshuatvernon - You could. But if you installed it with restrictive permission you will have issue using it for another user.

Comment: I install it just doing 'brew install zsh` and it works fine on both users

Comment: It's just `oh-my-zsh` that has the auto-complete and permission issues

Comment: @joshuatvernon - then use it

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I somehow got it to work however by installing oh-my-zsh as the root user sudo sh and then again as each admin user. I'm unsure as to whether this is bad usage however it is working and giving no permissions errors or completion errors.

Comment: What is step 6 for? Replace `export ZSH=.*`with `export ZSH='${ZSH}'`? I think you need an absolute or relative path, but not `$ZSH`.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst @alvits answer may have been correct I was unable to get it to work for me. I however, was able to get it to work by doing the following.

Install Homebrew (check https://brew.sh/ for up to date command):

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Install Zsh with Homebrew:

`brew install zsh`

Close terminal and reopen with ZSH as default shell:

Install Oh My Zsh as root user

`sudo su`

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Close terminal to exit root user mode.

Install Oh My Zsh as each admin (therefore install on both users):

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

That stopped all the auto-completions and permission errors for me. I believe this to be overkill and that there would be a way with symlinks however this way is easy.